# npm sudo global installation & unsafe-perm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install a npm module with:

```
sudo npm install -g now
```

However, when I try that, I get a warning:

> Warning! Please try installing Now CLI again with the `--unsafe-perm` option.
>   Example: `npm i -g --unsafe-perm now`

This ***unsafe*** permission worries me, and I want to make it clear *whether I need to follow it to fix the warning, or I can ignore it?*

The explanation at https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm doesn't really tell much, for me. This [commented from sam-github  on Mar 30, 2016](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-pm/issues/334#issuecomment-203638235) explains much more clearly about the implication.

However, even after reading the two several times, I'm still unclear what `--unsafe-perm` is doing, and what's the implication. So,

> - Default: false if running as root
> - Set to true to suppress the UID/GID switching when running package scripts.

Is the above two "*running*" telling about the same thing or different things? If it the same thing, then is it the install time or run time?

All I want is to be able to

- install it
- and let anyone in my system able to use it, with the *least security risk*

so what should I do?

Comment: are you trying to install `npm install capture-now` or `npm install now`

Comment: @antzshrek, `sudo npm install -g now`

Comment: okay. Posted a solution for you, I hopes it helps

Answer (score 11):

As you rightly read from [unsafe-perm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm)

- Default: false if running as root, true otherwise
- Type: Boolean

Set to true to suppress the UID/GID switching when running package scripts. If set explicitly to `false`, then installing as a non-root user will fail.

#### To answer your first question:

> All I want is to be able to install it, follow the steps below.

If you’re going to use `sudo` to install `now`, you need to specify the `--unsafe-perm` option to run `npm` as the root account. And you can as well do that directly from your terminal by running

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true -g now
```

#### To answer your next question:

> All I want is to be able to let anyone in my system able to use it, with the least security risk

I will advice you run your installation of `now` on root mood so that any user can use it and won't have the permission of uninstalling it by any means without the root permission. So maybe you should disregard the *regular practice*

Comment: _"Do not install modules locally with sudo. Never. It's unnecessary"_, if I don't do that, with `npm install -g now`, I'll get: `npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
`

Comment: As I said, it's just a warning. Funny enough, I also sometimes use `sudo`. But as I said in my answer, you can fix the `sudo` thing by running  `sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME /usr/lib/node_modules` from your terminal

Comment: actually, I don't think all my questions are answered, especially, _let anyone in my system able to use it_, and also _with least security risk_

Comment: Thanks antzshrek! "_If you’re going to use sudo to install now, you need to specify the --unsafe-perm option to run npm as the root account_". So why I have to do that? root+unsafe doesn't sound right to me. Why `sudo npm install` isn't good enough? what's the `unsafe ` brings that `sudo npm install` doesn't have?

Comment: you might want to read the issue you posted from https://github.com/strongloop/strong-pm/issues/334#issuecomment-203638235, it might help you understand `--unsafe`.

Comment: _"con: install scripts are run as root"_ and _"pro: without them, no install script can write to disk in its own module folder"_, isn't that reversed?