# Installing Appium via npm throw an error of "permission denied" type

Tags: android, node.js, npm, appium

Trying to install an appium package for node.js and have a problem referenced that permission been denied to mkdir

I tried to run this command in different ways and running as root user doesn't changed much. Have anybody had such an error before ?

```
Dmytros-MacBook-Pro:~ root# npm install -g appium
/usr/local/bin/appium -> 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js

> appium-chromedriver@4.0.0 install 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver
> node install-npm.js

(node:8302) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EACCES: 
permission denied, mkdir 
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium- 
chromedriver/201866-8302-85r6wr.u3tan'
(node:8302) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8302) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections 
are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled 
will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
info Chromedriver Install Installing Chromedriver version '2.38' for 
platform 'mac' and architecture '64'
info Chromedriver Install Opening temp file to write 
chromedriver_mac64 to...
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium- 
chromedriver/201866-8302-y2j8ui.tqs2'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! appium-chromedriver@4.0.0 install: `node install-npm.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the appium-chromedriver@4.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/root/.npm/_logs/2018-07-07T02_06_56_333Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 6):

This one command solved the problem

`sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

**Latest:**

- To install the latest version of [**Appium**](https://github.com/appium/appium), use the command below:

`sudo npm install -g appium@latest --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

**Versions:**

- To install a specific version of [**Appium**](https://github.com/appium/appium) e.g. **1.22.1**, use the command below:

`sudo npm install -g appium@1.22.1 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

Comment: I was attempting to install `appium` globally via npm on a user that was not the owner of `/usr/local/`. This caused the issues in the OP. Running this command solved my problems.

To add more context, I had wanted to follow up as to what the following command did.
`--unsafe-perm=true` [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084929/npm-sudo-global-installation-unsafe-perm). This solution is mentioned in [appium's Troubleshooting guide](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/troubleshooting/#general).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install specific version of appium then use below command.
I'm using 1.13 so I used the same below.

```
sudo npm install -g appium@1.20.2 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Let me know if you face any issues for installing specific version of appium.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

This command solved my issue as well

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the issue with the permissions for the desired folders. Whereas the above solutions works absolutely fine. None of them specified to use the latest build. I would suggest to always use the latest appium(or whatever) version. So, the ideal command is:
sudo npm install -g appium@latest --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root