# error installing firebase `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, firebase-tools

i am try to use `firebase-cloud-messaging` with javascipt

and i use this repo : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

in the Get Started i must run this command `npm install -g firebase-tools`. but i got error like this :

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! protobufjs@6.11.2 postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the protobufjs@6.11.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-28T09_18_46_217Z-debug.log
```

can anyone help and explain to me what's wrong it this, i have try any solution in google but still error like this.
Thanks

**Version node** : v14.18.1

**Version npm** : 6.14.15

**OS** : Linux Elementary 6

Comment: Have you tried `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools`?

Comment: yes, the first error is permission denied, then i add `sudo` in that command, and now the error be like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this:

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g firebase-tools
```

More about the `--unsafe-perm` can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084929/npm-sudo-global-installation-unsafe-perm)